# Qt5 Issue with using several setupUi

Tags: qt, user-interface, crash, qt5, qwidget

I'm trying to spread a different parts of a large UI in smaller UI files and then use in a project as a QWidgets.

Well, main idea is:

```
Ui::subelement * item;
QWidget * widget;
item->setupUi(widget);
widget->show();
```

But for some reason I cannot start setupUi() more than two times.

Once it's ui->setupUi(this) and second time it's ui_Menu. Thereafter, the program has unexpectedly finished.

Well if step-by-step, here is my code:

```
#include "ui_AdminManager.h"
#include "ui_AdminArea.h"
#include "ui_Menu.h"

...

class AdminManager : public QDialog {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit AdminManager(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~AdminManager();

private:
    Ui::AdminManager * ui;
    Ui::AdminArea    * ui_adminArea;
    Ui::Menu         * ui_Menu;
```

After that I try to initialize a widgets and show them:

```
AdminManager::AdminManager(QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent), ui(new Ui::AdminManager) {
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QObject::connect(this, SIGNAL(showTab(int)), ui->tabWidget, SLOT(setCurrentIndex(int)));
    LOG("hi");

    ui_adminArea->setupUi(ui->widgetSelectSite);
    ui->widgetSelectSite->show();
    LOG("hi");

    ui_Menu->setupUi(ui->widget);
    ui->widget->show();
    LOG("hi");
```

But I got an error and the program breaks if I do this.

```
Starting /APPS/AdminManager/bin/AdminManager...
../src/AdminManager.cpp 7 AdminManager : hi
The program has unexpectedly finished.
```

But everything works if I comment out one setupUi() call!

```
AdminManager::AdminManager(QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent), ui(new
Ui::AdminManager) {
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QObject::connect(this, SIGNAL(showTab(int)), ui->tabWidget, SLOT(setCurrentIndex(int)));
    LOG("hi");

//   ui_adminArea->setupUi(ui->widgetSelectSite); 
//   ui->widgetSelectSite->show();
     LOG("hi");

     ui_Menu->setupUi(ui->widget);
     ui->widget->show();
     LOG("hi");
```

Output:

```
Starting /APPS/AdminManager/bin/AdminManager...
../src/AdminManager.cpp 7 AdminManager : hi 
../src/AdminManager.cpp 11 AdminManager : hi 
../src/AdminManager.cpp 15 AdminManager : hi
```

I climbed inside of ui_AdminArea.h and see what this setupUi() do.

Put there some qDebug():

```
class Ui_AdminArea
{
public:
    QPushButton *pushButton;

    void setupUi(QWidget *AdminArea)
    {
        qDebug() << 1;
        if (AdminArea->objectName().isEmpty())
            AdminArea->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("AdminArea"));
        qDebug() << 2;
        AdminArea->resize(400, 300);
        qDebug() << 3;
        pushButton = new QPushButton(AdminArea);
        qDebug() << 4;
        pushButton->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("pushButton"));
        qDebug() << 5;
        pushButton->setGeometry(QRect(130, 100, 99, 27));
        qDebug() << 6;
        retranslateUi(AdminArea);
        qDebug() << 7;
        QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(AdminArea);
        qDebug() << 8;
    } // setupUi

    void retranslateUi(QWidget *AdminArea) { ... } // retranslateUi
};
```

And that's what I got in output:

```
Starting /APPS/AdminManager/bin/AdminManager...
../src/AdminManager.cpp 7 AdminManager : hi 
1 
2 
3 
The program has unexpectedly finished.
```

It turns out that something strange happend at the moment of **pushButton = new QPushButton(AdminArea)**.

And I cannot catch it.

BTW, in ui_Menu.h actually everything the same, one button and that's all...

Can someone tell me how to solve this issue?

---

**PS.** It's clear test project with the same issue [on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/cYN16Tr8)

**PPS.** [for test all files](http://ge.tt/7pTkXkn1) and [in one archive](http://ge.tt/2P9Qckn1)

---

**UPD.** It solved. I just not init that liks...

```
Ui::AdminArea * ui_adminArea;

ui_adminArea = new Ui::AdminArea;
ui_adminArea->setupUi(ui->widgetSelectSite);
ui->widgetSelectSite->show();

Ui::Menu * ui_Menu;

ui_Menu = new Ui::Menu;
ui_Menu->setupUi(ui->widget);
ui->widget->show();
```

Comment: It's clear test project with the same issue: http://pastebin.com/cYN16Tr8

Comment: for test all files: http://ge.tt/7pTkXkn1 and in one archive: http://ge.tt/2P9Qckn1

Comment: [ SOLVED !!! ] I forgot to initialize *ui_test1 )))
So... was Ui::Test1 * ui_test1 and before to do ui_test1->setupUi(ui->widget1) I must do: ui_test1 = new Ui::Test1